# Assign d3.js Axis a Background Color and Change Layer Ordering

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, d3.js

Currently when you move the circles around, they will move over the axes and obscure them. I am trying to assign a background color to the axes so the circles move underneath the axe. However using CSS `background` attribute does not seem to do anything.

How would you create an opaque axis that will be a layer above the circles?

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/PXw5E/1/

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting the axes to be drawn on top of the dots is done easily by changing the order in which you append the dom elements. [See example](http://jsfiddle.net/PXw5E/2/).

Assigning a css background to the axes is not possible, because they are drawn with SVG. You'll need to draw it either using `rects` or a `path`.

If the background you intend to draw is fully opaque (i.e. alpha of 1), it would be more straight forward to skip drawing a background and instead use svg clip-rect to crop the circles. That would not work if you want the axes to have a semi-transparent background though.

Answer (score 0):

SVG stack graph in orden you add it, to change it change added order.

You can change axes style on your CSS

```
.axis text {
  font: 9px sans-serif;
  color: #8c8c8c;
}
.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #d9dee9;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
```

On d3 you have line, path and text 'stroke' surrounding 'fill'

here you can see working styling, including layering objects: http://jsfiddle.net/klaujesi/rwhp8yjq/

Comment: @RobertLongson that's style axis. SVG stack graph in orden you add it, to change it change added order